# Meaning of “on the low side”

Tags: slang, colloquial-language

I was talking to a recruiter and she said that “ your maths skill is a bit on the low side”. Did she mean that my maths is very low in the score distribution of all candidates (i’m thinking about the left side of the bell curve) or do I just lack a bit if maths to be the right candidate?

Thanks

Comment: Either way, she was saying you're not very good at math.

Answer (score 3):

"*On the low side*" literally means lower than the average, but is often used as a *euphemism* for "very bad" when people don't want to say that directly.

Without the complete context, it's impossible to say, and even with a video of the call, it might still be unclear whether the recruiter meant "a little bit low" or "waaaaaay too low".

You'd probably have to directly ask what she meant when she said that.

Answer (score 0):

It means she believes your math skills are poor relative to other candidates or to the requirements for the role.

If this comment surprises you, you need to discuss it with her. Either you have underestimated the math skills required for the role, or she has bad information about your abilities. Until you resolve the issue, your perceived weak math skills are probably going to prevent you from getting a job offer.